# How to return sorted values in a function

Tags: python, function, numpy, sorting

```
def draw_new_r(r_list):
    delta_r = np.random.uniform(low = -0.1, high= 0.1, size =3)
    return np.maximum(0,r_list+delta_r)

draw_new_r(np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.8]))
```

it returns an array which is sorted like  [0.23855333 0.36313398 0.86038547]

```
draw_new_r(np.array([0.39, 0.4, 0.8]))
```

it returns an array which is not sorted like [0.47735026, 0.46623568, 0.70666558]
How can i edit this def function which always will return sorted values of the random function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)?

```
def draw_new_r(r_list):
    delta_r = np.random.uniform(low = -0.1, high= 0.1, size =3)
    return np.sort(np.maximum(0,r_list+delta_r))
```